# Hibernate map string value to a sql enum using custom user type

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I try to map a string value to sql enum, but I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "state" is of type double_state, and the expression - character varying
```

I am using the following code:

.hbm.xml mapping entry

```
<property name="state" type="helper.entity.util.DoubleStateUserType">
    <column name="state" not-null="true"/>
</property>
```

the following UserType implementation nullSafeSet function:

```
@Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index,
                            SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (null == value) {
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setString(index, (String) value);
        }
    }
```

The state column in the table is an enum of two values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<property name="state" column="state" not-null="true">
      <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
         <param name="enumClass">helper.entity.util.DoubleStateUserType
         <param name="type">12
      </type>
    </property>
```

By default Hibernate persists the enumeration value as integer in the database when 'type' param is not specified, we  need to store the enum display name in database so we can map it to 12 which is equivalent to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it works only, if the column type is text/string. Is doesn't work, if the column type is sql enum. I read somewhere, that sql enums are evil, so now I remade all my enums to be extra tables.